# Vector containing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, notation

I have a list/vector of $n$ elements where each element is a matrix of size $a\times b$.

What is the conventional name of this and how do I define or represent it mathematically?

Comment: @Relgram: If your "list" is $l$ then each element $l_i$ is a $a \times b$ matrix whose $(j,k)$-th element can be denoted by $(l_i)_{jk} = l_{ijk}$. The $n \times a \times b$ scalars $l_{ijk}$ can be thought of a multi-dimensional array and such an object is called a tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your matrices are over the reals. We write $\mathbb{R}$ to denote the ("set of") real numbers. Then $M_{a\times b}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set (actually, vector space) of $a\times b$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

So you are asking about this set:

$(M_{a\times b}(\mathbb{R}))^n$
(where $"-^n"$ is the cartesian product n times; so this is the cartesian product n times of the set of $a\times b$ matrices over the reals; "over the reals" meaning that the entries of the matrices are in the reals)

But actually, as far as we are concerned in linear algebra, this set is really just:

$M_{(an)\times b}(\mathbb{R})$
(the set of $(an)\times b$ matrices over the reals)

The reason is that $(M_{a\times b}(\mathbb{R}))^n$ is a vector space of dimension nab over the reals, and so is $M_{(an)\times b}(\mathbb{R})$, which implies that they are isomorphic as vector spaces. It is because of the coordinate map, which, for our purposes in this context, takes matrices, say $(an)\times b$ matries (which are really the same as vectors of n entries, each entry being an $a\times b$ matrix), to vectors with abn entries like this:

$\begin{pmatrix} a_1\\ a_2\\ \vdots \\ a_{abn-1}\\ a_{abn}\end{pmatrix}$.

These vectors are really the same as $(an)\times b$ matrices (as far as linear algebra is concerned).